# Spring Post Form @RequestBody cannot be bound as MultiValueMap

Tags: forms, spring-boot, post, kotlin

My controller is this:

```
@PostMapping("/car/{id}/book", consumes = 
[MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE])
    fun orderProcess(model: Model,
                     @PathVariable id: Int,
                     @Valid customerBindingModel: CustomerBindingModel,
                     bindingResult: BindingResult,
                     request: HttpServletRequest,
                     @RequestBody multiParams: MultiValueMap<String, String>) : String {
        println(multiParams)

        val params = multiParams.toSingleValueMap()

        println(params)
        val startDateString = params["datetime_pick"]!!
        val endDateString = params["datetime_off"]!!
        ...
}
```

My view is this:

```
<form th:action="@{/car/{id}/book(id=${car.id})}" id="confirmForm" method="POST">
<div class="formrow">
    <input type="hidden" id="startDate" name="startDate" th:value="${param.datetime_pick[0]}" />
    <input type="hidden" id="endDate" name="endDate" th:value="${param.datetime_off[0]}" />


    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" th:value="${customer.email}" />

    <label for="phoneNumber">Телефон</label>
    <input type="tel" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" th:value="${customer.phoneNumber}" />
    <script th:src="@{/intl-tel-input-12.1.0/build/js/intlTelInput.js}"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->

    <br/>
    <label class="check-container">Сега ще платя депозит:
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="payDepositNow" th:checked="${payDepositNow}">
                                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                            </label>


    <script>
        $("#phoneNumber").intlTelInput({
                                                    nationalMode: false,
                                                    preferredCountries: ['bg'],
                                                });
    </script>

</div>
```

The problem is that I get a NPE (Null pointer) I tried all sorts of things to get the body of the function normally. I mean I could just get it with splitting a url encoded string, but I kind of wanted to get it as a map.
I could also make a function to transform the `@RequestBody params: String` to a map myself, but there must be a better way to get the body as a map. The NPE must be somewhere around the assertions (`!!`)

If I try to get the data as `@RequestParam param: String` I obviously can't, because the data is in the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to get `datetime_pick`, but there was no such parameter in the form, there is `startDate`. Dumb me XD.